# how to hide keyboard on view disappear or button click iphone

Tags: iphone, keyboard, hide

I have a table view on a view and table view contains custom cells and cell contains text box. and i want to hide the keyboard when user click on save button or user navigate from the view.
i already have hide the keyboard on done button.. plz can any one suggest.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the following code

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

}
```

It will dismiss your keyboard when ever your view is dismissed.

If on clicking save button your view is not getting dismissed then on SAVE button Click event also you have to write `[textField resignFirstResponder];` else it will work.

**Update:**
If you cannot track the textfield or there are too many textfields then using

`[self.view endEditing:YES];`

in your `viewWillDisappear`will do the trick.

Comment: I dont think theres any problem in the answer. Atleast provide comment for downvoting...

Answer (score 25):

If you want to hide the keyboard with the tap of a button and if you have many text fields and the user can be on any field. Then you can use this code:

`[self.view endEditing:YES];`

Tap any where on view, and keyboard will dissappear..

Njoy.. :)

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to resign your text box from being the firstResponder :

```
[textbox resignFirstResponder];
```

Put that in the method called when you click on save and you'll be good to go

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the keyboard like this:

```
 //swift
  self.view.endEditing(true)

 //obj-c
 [self.view endEditing:YES];
```